# How to bind to an input element using a view model created by the knockout.viewmodel plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

I'm using knockout with the knockout.viewmodel plugin. http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/

```
// JavaScript
// data variable is loaded from an ajax call
/*
   var data = { simple: { friendlyText: "Hello World" } };
*/
viewmodel.scenario = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(data, options);

<!-- HTML Page -->
<!-- This does not bind -->
<input type="text" length="50" data-bind="textInput: scenario.simple.friendlyText" />

<!-- This does bind -->
<label data-bind="text: scenario.simple.friendlyText"></label>
```

What's special about the textInput binding on the `input` element that I'm missing or not doing?

Comment: Sounds like it's making a dependent (read-only) observable. That would explain why it won't work for text**Input**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have picked the knockout-2.0 tag for your question. If you are indeed using knockout version 2, then textInput will not work, as it was added at a later time. In [Version 3.2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/08/18/knockout-3-2-0-released/)

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.  I'm using the SPA template from Visual Studio and didn't think that the knockout version would be that old.